# Comparing Two instances of the same object in a list

Tags: java, list

I am trying to compare two objects to see if they are the same. I create the first List from JSON code and populate the List (data) with an instance of InstructionModel. I then compare the data to a database by selecting the data and creating a new instance (model) of InstructionModel. But the result is always false, what am I doing wrong in my code?

```
exists = data.contains(model);

if(!exists)
{
    //Do Some Stuff Here
}
```

Data from a `List<InstructionModel>`:
[image]
Data in InstructionModel Object:
[image]

Comment: How do you know that result is always false?

Comment: How is `equals` implemented in `InstructionModel`? If it's not overridden, then `contains` is checking whether the actual object is present, which is of course false.

Comment: Did you implement equals?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to override the equals-method for your InstructionModel class.
In this method you compare your values and return true if they match, false if they don't.

The [`List#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) function will use the `Object#equals` function of the objects in the container. If this function is not overriden it will compare references only, not the actual values.

Addition:
As the comments mention, if you override the 'equals' method, than you need to override the 'hashCode' method, too (and vice versa). Collections will work with these methods to compare your instances of objects. For example: If you don't override both, two instances might be considered the same in a List, but not the same in a ['Hashmap'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: And remember that the hashcode method must also be reimplemented, so if `a.equals(b)`, then `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode();`

Comment: @SJuan76 I understand overriding the equals method but why must I override the hashCode method too? and what Do I override that with?

Comment: Because its specifications say that the above stated property must be true. A lot of logic expects it to be true (for example, `HashMap`s and the like).

Answer (score 1):

You might like to override the `equals` method on `InstructionModel`.